Multiple authentication Identity - JWT
I have a project where the web is authenticated with an identity and I want to use JWT for APIs. What changes should I make to use both at the same time?
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Logout";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(43200);
            });

Simultaneous use of JWT and Identity

You could try following codes:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
//add cookie scheme
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
//add jwt scheme
                .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>{...}
                     );

//Add a policy called "Jwt_Or_Cookie" to allow either jwt or cookie.
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Jwt_Or_Cookie", policy =>
    {
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();

    });
});

Then you could use this policy which allows both scheme
        [Authorize(Policy = "Jwt_Or_Cookie")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {...}

